# How to make every \begin{titlepage} in odd page

Tags: titles, page, clearpage

I want to make every `\begin{titlepage}` in my code is always in odd page. I've try add `\cleardoublepage` and `\clearpage`, but  not working. This is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=215mm,top=4cm,left=4cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 \newgeometry{top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm} 
 \begin{titlepage}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN SAMPUL}
\pagestyle{fancy}                                                                       %Menghilangkan nomor halaman 
 \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
\includegraphics[width=3.2cm,height=3.5cm]{logo.png}\\                                      %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                        %environment akhir gambar
  \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                            %memulai rata tengah
\fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {TITLE}\\
    % \textbf=bold dan \textit=italic 
 \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                             %spasi vertikal sejauh 1.5cm 
 \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{SKRIPSI}}\\
 \vspace{3.5cm}

 \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{NAME\\111111}}\\

  \vspace{5cm}
\fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont{ \textbf{PROGRAM STUDI DDD\\
 FAKULTAS MATEMATIKA DAN ILMU PENGETAHUAN ALAM\\
 UNIVERSITAS DDD}}\\
\fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont {\textbf{DESEMBER, 2019}}
 \end{titlepage}

 \begin{titlepage}
 \cleardoublepage
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN JUDUL}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \setcounter{page}{2}
                                                                    %Menghilangkan nomor halaman 
 \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
\includegraphics[width=3.2cm,height=3.5cm]{logo.png}\\                                      %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                        %environment akhir gambar
  \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                            %memulai rata tengah
\fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {TITLE}\\
    % \textbf=bold dan \textit=italic 
 \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                             %spasi vertikal sejauh 1.5cm 
 \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{SKRIPSI}}\\
 \vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont { \textbf{Diajukan untuk memenuhi salah satu persyaratan\\
dalam menyelesaikan Program Sarjana Strata Satu (S1)\\
Program Studi Matematika pada Jurusan Matematika FMIPA Universitas\\
Der\\}}
 \vspace{1cm}
 \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{NAME\\111111}}\\

  \vspace{5cm}
\fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont{ \textbf{PROGRAM STUDI DDD\\
 FAKULTAS MATEMATIKA DAN ILMU PENGETAHUAN ALAM\\
 UNIVERSITAS DDD}}\\
\fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont {\textbf{DESEMBER, 2019}}

 \end{titlepage}

 \restoregeometry

 \begin{titlepage}
 \setcounter{page}{6}
 \centering 
 {\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{PERSETUJUAN PEMBIMBING}}}
 \vspace{36pt}
 \begin{flushleft}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% local to flushleft
 \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}@{:\space}p{11cm}}
 Judul&\textbf{TITLE}\\[1\baselineskip]
 Nama&\textbf{NAME}\\[1\baselineskip]
 Stambuk&\textbf{111111}\\
 \end{tabular}\\
 \vspace{24pt}
 Telah diperiksa dan disetujui untuk diajukan pada Seminar Hasil\\
 \vspace{24pt}
 \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{6cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{6cm}}
 &Palu, 15 Desember 2019\\
 Mengetahui,\\
 Ketua Jurusan DDD&Pembimbing\\
 FMIPA Universitas DDD \\[3\baselineskip]
 \underline{\textbf{NAME}}&\underline{\textbf{NAME}} \\
 NIP. 111& NIP. 1111\\
 \end{tabular*}
 \end{flushleft}
 \end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}
  \setcounter{page}{4}
  \centering 
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{PENGESAHAN DEWAN PENGUJI}}}
\vspace{24pt}
\begin{flushleft}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% local to flushleft
\begin{tabular}{p{3.3cm}@{:\space\quad}p{11cm}}
Judul&\textbf{TITLE}\\[1\baselineskip]
Nama&\textbf{NAME}\\[1\baselineskip]
Stambuk&\textbf{1111}\\[1\baselineskip]
Disetujui Tanggal& \\
\end{tabular}\\
\vspace{24pt}
\textbf{DEWAN PENGUJI}\\
\vspace{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{3.3cm}@{:\space\quad}p{8cm}@{\space}p{4cm}}
Nama&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\[1\baselineskip]
Sekretaris&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\[1\baselineskip]
Penguji 1&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\[1\baselineskip]
Penguji 2&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\[1\baselineskip]
Penguji 3&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\
\end{tabular}\\
\end{flushleft}
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
\begin{titlepage}

  \setcounter{page}{5}
  \begin{center}
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{HALAMAN PERNYATAAN\\}}}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN PERNYATAAN}
\vspace{36pt}
\doublespacing{
Dengan ini saya menyatakan bahwa dalan tugas akhir ini tidak terdapat karya
yang pernah diajukan untuk memperoleh gelar kesarjanaan di suatu Perguruan
Tinggi, dan sepanjang pengetahuan saya juga tidak terdapat karya atau pendapat
yang pernah ditulis atau diterbitkan oleh orang lain, kecuali yang secara tertulis
diacu dalam naskah ini dan disebutkan dalam daftar pustaka.}\\
\hspace*{10cm}Palu, 19 Desember 2019\\
\hspace*{10cm}Penulis,\\
\vspace{36pt}\\
\hspace*{10cm}NAME\\
\hspace*{10cm}1111\\

\end{titlepage}

 \tableofcontents
 \listoffigures
 \listoftables
\end{document}
```

Comment: instead of a title page why not make a `custom` page separately and then `call` it through `input` or `include`

Comment: Unrelated to your question but `\fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont` ????  why are you specifying a 14pt font to be placed on lines that are 12pt apart? (also the `{..}` group after `\selectfont` does nothing here.

Comment: @jsbibra: The question is not very clear, I agree. However, without knowing the full intentions of the questioner, your edit is going too far. Right now, my interpretation is that the question is about having each titlepage on an odd page. With your edit, the question reads as how to automatically get a titlepage on each odd page. These two are, however, very different questions.

Comment: possibly @Eddy can clarify if the edit is correct or not

Comment: @Tiuri, I want to make the titlepage only in odd page. So, the even page is only a blank page. please run my code

Comment: @jsbibra, some with above

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Please add the missing packages. After fixing the code, I still don't know what you want to achieve. Can you maybe make a detailed list of which pages you want to have in the output, especially between which parts of your document you want to have empty pages. Right now, the question is too unclear to give an answer.

Comment: @Tiuri, I think the code only missing picture file (because the picture must some folder). just make even page blank, and odd page is the titlepage.

Comment: No, it's not just the missing picture file - there are packages missing. And it's still unclear what you want to achieve. Please, explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: @Tiuri, this problem is solve. Now, check the next problem from this solving problem [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520771/how-to-add-page-numbering-in-begintitlepage?noredirect=1#comment1317004_520771)

Answer (score 2):

Issue a single `\setcounter{page}` command after the series of `titlepage` environments and do

```
\cleardoublepage
\begin{titlepage}
```

instead of the converse.

It makes no sense to set the page number inside `titlepage`.

Comment: the problem about odd page is clear. But
how to make the pages still have page numbers?. If I remove the `\setcounter{page}` the pages will be no number in table of contents. How to fix it?

Comment: @Eddy What's the reason for setting the page number? And if you want them to be on right-hand pages, they should have an odd page number, shouldn't they?

Comment: No, This is the titlepage, and my format thesis. After this titlepage, I have many chapter. I have set the page numbering for the chapter on right-hand pages. But for this titlepage, the page number is in the middle pages.

Comment: @Eddy A title page in the middle of a document? I can't understand.

Comment: Not like that. I mean the titlepage have the page numbering too. But the posisition of page number is different with the chapter. 
where the page number of my Chapter is on the lower right. While I want the location of the page number of the titlepage to be in the bottom center, not in the middle of the document.

Comment: [Something like this](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Gjo-A40NGwg/WrMbGVieMYI/AAAAAAAAHQQ/YPc9WQ_C3d8YIW5eCPfv5iR68d1NEVl5QCLcBGAs/s1600/page-number-ms-word.jpg)