# How to add page numbering in \begin{titlepage}?

Tags: titles, page-numbering

How to add page numbering in my code without adding `\setcounter{page}` ?
this is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=215mm,top=4cm,left=4cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 \newgeometry{top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm} 
 \begin{titlepage}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN SAMPUL}
\pagestyle{fancy}                                                                       %Menghilangkan nomor halaman 
 \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
\includegraphics[width=3.2cm,height=3.5cm]{logo.png}\\                                      %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                        %environment akhir gambar
  \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                            %memulai rata tengah
\fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {TITLE}\\
    % \textbf=bold dan \textit=italic 
 \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                             %spasi vertikal sejauh 1.5cm 
 \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{SKRIPSI}}\\
 \vspace{3.5cm}

 \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{NAME\\111111}}\\

  \vspace{5cm}
\fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont{ \textbf{PROGRAM STUDI DDD\\
 FAKULTAS MATEMATIKA DAN ILMU PENGETAHUAN ALAM\\
 UNIVERSITAS DDD}}\\
\fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont {\textbf{DESEMBER, 2019}}
 \end{titlepage}

 \begin{titlepage}
 \cleardoublepage
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN JUDUL}
 \pagestyle{fancy}

                                                                    %Menghilangkan nomor halaman 
 \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
\includegraphics[width=3.2cm,height=3.5cm]{logo.png}\\                                      %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                        %environment akhir gambar
  \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                            %memulai rata tengah
\fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {TITLE}\\
    % \textbf=bold dan \textit=italic 
 \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                             %spasi vertikal sejauh 1.5cm 
 \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{SKRIPSI}}\\
 \vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont { \textbf{Diajukan untuk memenuhi salah satu persyaratan\\
dalam menyelesaikan Program Sarjana Strata Satu (S1)\\
Program Studi Matematika pada Jurusan Matematika FMIPA Universitas\\
Der\\}}
 \vspace{1cm}
 \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{NAME\\111111}}\\

  \vspace{5cm}
\fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont{ \textbf{PROGRAM STUDI DDD\\
 FAKULTAS MATEMATIKA DAN ILMU PENGETAHUAN ALAM\\
 UNIVERSITAS DDD}}\\
\fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont {\textbf{DESEMBER, 2019}}

 \end{titlepage}

 \restoregeometry

 \begin{titlepage}

 \centering 
 {\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{PERSETUJUAN PEMBIMBING}}}
 \vspace{36pt}
 \begin{flushleft}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% local to flushleft
 \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}@{:\space}p{11cm}}
 Judul&\textbf{TITLE}\\[1\baselineskip]
 Nama&\textbf{NAME}\\[1\baselineskip]
 Stambuk&\textbf{111111}\\
 \end{tabular}\\
 \vspace{24pt}
 Telah diperiksa dan disetujui untuk diajukan pada Seminar Hasil\\
 \vspace{24pt}
 \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{6cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{6cm}}
 &Palu, 15 Desember 2019\\
 Mengetahui,\\
 Ketua Jurusan DDD&Pembimbing\\
 FMIPA Universitas DDD \\[3\baselineskip]
 \underline{\textbf{NAME}}&\underline{\textbf{NAME}} \\
 NIP. 111& NIP. 1111\\
 \end{tabular*}
 \end{flushleft}
 \end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}

  \centering 
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{PENGESAHAN DEWAN PENGUJI}}}
\vspace{24pt}
\begin{flushleft}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% local to flushleft
\begin{tabular}{p{3.3cm}@{:\space\quad}p{11cm}}
Judul&\textbf{TITLE}\\[1\baselineskip]
Nama&\textbf{NAME}\\[1\baselineskip]
Stambuk&\textbf{1111}\\[1\baselineskip]
Disetujui Tanggal& \\
\end{tabular}\\
\vspace{24pt}
\textbf{DEWAN PENGUJI}\\
\vspace{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{3.3cm}@{:\space\quad}p{8cm}@{\space}p{4cm}}
Nama&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\[1\baselineskip]
Sekretaris&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\[1\baselineskip]
Penguji 1&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\[1\baselineskip]
Penguji 2&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\[1\baselineskip]
Penguji 3&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\
\end{tabular}\\
\end{flushleft}
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
\begin{titlepage}


  \begin{center}
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{HALAMAN PERNYATAAN\\}}}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN PERNYATAAN}
\vspace{36pt}
\doublespacing{
Dengan ini saya menyatakan bahwa dalan tugas akhir ini tidak terdapat karya
yang pernah diajukan untuk memperoleh gelar kesarjanaan di suatu Perguruan
Tinggi, dan sepanjang pengetahuan saya juga tidak terdapat karya atau pendapat
yang pernah ditulis atau diterbitkan oleh orang lain, kecuali yang secara tertulis
diacu dalam naskah ini dan disebutkan dalam daftar pustaka.}\\
\hspace*{10cm}Palu, 19 Desember 2019\\
\hspace*{10cm}Penulis,\\
\vspace{36pt}\\
\hspace*{10cm}NAME\\
\hspace*{10cm}1111\\

\end{titlepage}

 \tableofcontents
 \listoffigures
 \listoftables
\end{document}
```

Because if I add \setcounter{page}, the \begin{titlepage} will not start in every odd page. This is I mean.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=215mm,top=4cm,left=4cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 \newgeometry{top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm} 
 \begin{titlepage}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN SAMPUL}
\pagestyle{fancy}                                                                       %Menghilangkan nomor halaman 
 \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
\includegraphics[width=3.2cm,height=3.5cm]{logo.png}\\                                      %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                        %environment akhir gambar
  \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                            %memulai rata tengah
\fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {TITLE}\\
    % \textbf=bold dan \textit=italic 
 \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                             %spasi vertikal sejauh 1.5cm 
 \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{SKRIPSI}}\\
 \vspace{3.5cm}

 \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{NAME\\111111}}\\

  \vspace{5cm}
\fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont{ \textbf{PROGRAM STUDI DDD\\
 FAKULTAS MATEMATIKA DAN ILMU PENGETAHUAN ALAM\\
 UNIVERSITAS DDD}}\\
\fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont {\textbf{DESEMBER, 2019}}
 \end{titlepage}

 \begin{titlepage}
 \cleardoublepage
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN JUDUL}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \setcounter{page}{2}
                                                                    %Menghilangkan nomor halaman 
 \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
\includegraphics[width=3.2cm,height=3.5cm]{logo.png}\\                                      %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                        %environment akhir gambar
  \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                            %memulai rata tengah
\fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {TITLE}\\
    % \textbf=bold dan \textit=italic 
 \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                             %spasi vertikal sejauh 1.5cm 
 \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{SKRIPSI}}\\
 \vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont { \textbf{Diajukan untuk memenuhi salah satu persyaratan\\
dalam menyelesaikan Program Sarjana Strata Satu (S1)\\
Program Studi Matematika pada Jurusan Matematika FMIPA Universitas\\
Der\\}}
 \vspace{1cm}
 \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{NAME\\111111}}\\

  \vspace{5cm}
\fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont{ \textbf{PROGRAM STUDI DDD\\
 FAKULTAS MATEMATIKA DAN ILMU PENGETAHUAN ALAM\\
 UNIVERSITAS DDD}}\\
\fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont {\textbf{DESEMBER, 2019}}

 \end{titlepage}

 \restoregeometry

 \begin{titlepage}
 \setcounter{page}{6}
 \centering 
 {\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{PERSETUJUAN PEMBIMBING}}}
 \vspace{36pt}
 \begin{flushleft}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% local to flushleft
 \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}@{:\space}p{11cm}}
 Judul&\textbf{TITLE}\\[1\baselineskip]
 Nama&\textbf{NAME}\\[1\baselineskip]
 Stambuk&\textbf{111111}\\
 \end{tabular}\\
 \vspace{24pt}
 Telah diperiksa dan disetujui untuk diajukan pada Seminar Hasil\\
 \vspace{24pt}
 \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{6cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{6cm}}
 &Palu, 15 Desember 2019\\
 Mengetahui,\\
 Ketua Jurusan DDD&Pembimbing\\
 FMIPA Universitas DDD \\[3\baselineskip]
 \underline{\textbf{NAME}}&\underline{\textbf{NAME}} \\
 NIP. 111& NIP. 1111\\
 \end{tabular*}
 \end{flushleft}
 \end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}
  \setcounter{page}{4}
  \centering 
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{PENGESAHAN DEWAN PENGUJI}}}
\vspace{24pt}
\begin{flushleft}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% local to flushleft
\begin{tabular}{p{3.3cm}@{:\space\quad}p{11cm}}
Judul&\textbf{TITLE}\\[1\baselineskip]
Nama&\textbf{NAME}\\[1\baselineskip]
Stambuk&\textbf{1111}\\[1\baselineskip]
Disetujui Tanggal& \\
\end{tabular}\\
\vspace{24pt}
\textbf{DEWAN PENGUJI}\\
\vspace{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{3.3cm}@{:\space\quad}p{8cm}@{\space}p{4cm}}
Nama&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\[1\baselineskip]
Sekretaris&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\[1\baselineskip]
Penguji 1&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\[1\baselineskip]
Penguji 2&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\[1\baselineskip]
Penguji 3&\textbf{NAME}&...............\\
\end{tabular}\\
\end{flushleft}
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
\begin{titlepage}

  \setcounter{page}{5}
  \begin{center}
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{HALAMAN PERNYATAAN\\}}}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN PERNYATAAN}
\vspace{36pt}
\doublespacing{
Dengan ini saya menyatakan bahwa dalan tugas akhir ini tidak terdapat karya
yang pernah diajukan untuk memperoleh gelar kesarjanaan di suatu Perguruan
Tinggi, dan sepanjang pengetahuan saya juga tidak terdapat karya atau pendapat
yang pernah ditulis atau diterbitkan oleh orang lain, kecuali yang secara tertulis
diacu dalam naskah ini dan disebutkan dalam daftar pustaka.}\\
\hspace*{10cm}Palu, 19 Desember 2019\\
\hspace*{10cm}Penulis,\\
\vspace{36pt}\\
\hspace*{10cm}NAME\\
\hspace*{10cm}1111\\

\end{titlepage}

 \tableofcontents
 \listoffigures
 \listoftables
\end{document}
```

I want to add page numbering, but the titlepage always shown in odd pege like the first code. `\setcounter{page}` make the \begin{titlepage} will display in even page. Unfortunately, I dont want the \begin{titlepage} shown in even page.

Comment: Please clarify your previous question instead of posting it as a new question!

Comment: @Tiuri, yeah. That's my related questions. And the related question is fix. But, when I use the new code. The page numbering is gone. How to add the page numbering ?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think this is a duplicate.  It sounds like the questioner isn't asking about starting on an odd page, but about keeping an actual printed folio on the title page.  @Eddy, can you confirm?

Comment: @dgoodmaniii, I don't get what you mean. But, apart from that for this case, I want this code to run on just odd pages. And for the contents section, it runs reciprocally between even pages and odd pages (But I don't display the content part because it's too long)